# Select from different tables based on condition

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'd like to select from different tables based on a parameter, is it possible to do this? Both tables have a compatible structure.

```
select * from
  (
    case when p_target then
      select * from table_a
    else
      select * from table_b
    end
  );
```

Comment: This sounds like a really bad data model. You should have a single table with a column `target` (or something similar), then you can simply do `select * from the_table where target = p_target`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's not really a data model, it's actually many different ways of generating a series, i.e. every minute for 0 to 59 or stepping through 2 date ranges every x days or weeks etc. With that generated series I then join my report data which results in the user's desired aggregation + unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though that this is not best practice at all, and you should really look at your data model, here is a way to do it:

```
with table_a as (
select 1::int, 'a'::text param
), table_b as (
select 2::int, 'b'::text param
)
select *
from (
    select *
    from table_a
    union all
    select *
    from table_b
) rs
where param = 'a'
```

Just add a parameter column to all tables, union them, and then have them all in a subquery, from which you can select the parameter of the particular table.

Answer (score 2):

Georgi's answer best resolves the question I asked, so for future readers that's likely to be the right answer.

However for my situation I took a different approach, I encapsulated that table swapping functionality into a procedure which looks like the following:

```
create function table_swap(p_target character varying)
  returns TABLE(id int)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin     
case
  when p_target = 'a' then
    return query
      select * from table_a;

  when p_target = 'b' then
    return query
      select * from table_b;

  else
    return;
 end case;
```

Which then allowed me to do the following

```
select * from table_swap(p_target);
```